# Получение данных с сервера(python) и вывод в андроид

Tags: android, python-3.x, android-studio, get, pycharm

Есть сервер на python, он получает данные с микроконтроллера и записывает в несколько .txt файлов. Подскажите как правильно получить к ним доступ и периодически считывать и выводить информацию.
Если сталкивались с подобными темами дайте ссылку.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Как минимум надо чтобы сервер на python отдавал их по протоколу http, а android-клиент периодически запрашивал данные у сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите какой нибудь flask (веб-фреймворк для python), и выводите через Http в json формате нужные данные, желательно еще бы писать все в какую нибудь базу, а не текстовые файлы, хотя можно данные и из текстовых файлов брать.